# pyinstaller is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: pyinstaller

I was able to create the path and install pyinstaller appropriately.

> C:\Users\Ankit.Aggarwal>pip install pyinstaller
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in 
>       c:\users\ankit.aggarwal\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
>   (3.4)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (39.0.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1
>   in c:\users\ankit.aggarwal\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
>   (from pyinstaller) (2018.8.8)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: macholib>=1.8 in 
>   c:\users\ankit.aggarwal\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
>   (from pyinstaller) (1.11)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in
>
> c:\users\ankit.aggarwal\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
>   (from pyinstaller) (0.16.1)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes in c:\users\ankit.aggarwal\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
>   (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: future in 
>       c:\users\ankit.aggarwal\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
>   (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.17.1) 
>    C:\Users\Ankit.Aggarwal>pyinstaller
>
> 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

However , getting above error on executing simple pyinstaller command. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the path for pyinstaller is correct? When you run the command, pip says pyinstaller is located in

```
c:\users\ankit.aggarwal\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-package
```

I have no idea if this will work, and I have never experienced this problem, but it looks like you may be looking in the wrong directory for pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

Figured ; added above path

```
C:\Users\Ankit.Aggarwal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall pyinstaller,If you have already installed & run thr following command :

```
  ***python -m PyInstaller --onefile --windowed --name="fileName" Homework.py***
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have admin rights before you run the commands. cmd - Run as administrator will ensure that you have logged in as administrator.