# Whenever I try to run pyinstaller, it says that it's not installed

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When I try to install PyInstaller, I get this:

```
C:\Users\user>pip install pyinstaller
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (4.10)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2022.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (57.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

And when tried running it, I get an error like this: `'pyinstaller' is not internal or external command, executable program, or batch file.` (had to translate from russian)

The [official documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io) wasn't any helpful for my case. Another questions like this weren't my rescue.

Comment: you could try to install a previous version: pip install pyinstaller==4.9

Answer (score 0):

##### You need to add the location of the package to your environmnet variables

Press the windows key, type "PATH", press enter, click on environment variable, then in system variables, find the "Path" one, click on modify, then new, and paste the location of the package : `c:\python310\lib\site-packages`, then click ok/apply.
You could have to reboot, but then you should be ok.

There is more help [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471411/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progr?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

It said use this command.

```
C:\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

maybe this problem is for your python version or pip version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).